# how get authenticate user from facebook and how i get Profile data from graph api in java

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

my task to authenticate user from facebook and get profile data using graph Api in  java,
i got the [example](http://javapapers.com/java/java-facebook-login-with-oauth-authentication/) and run it, its works 
**Problem**
I am getting only facebook Id and Name in graph Api. What are the changes  have to do in the [example](http://javapapers.com/java/java-facebook-login-with-oauth-authentication/) get the email, mobile, and other information of user

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to get access token with permissions like "email" and others?